# Java Cipher AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding with 32 bytes keys

Tags: java, cryptography, aes

In Jave, when creating a Cipher instance for AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding, how is it possible to use a key that has 32 bytes (and an IV of 16 bytes) when AES-128 uses 16 bytes keys?

Comment: If your key is numeric use BCD type by using \x before it. "12" is 2 bytes but "\x1\x2" is 1 byte.

Comment: The Java `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` transform (in fact all `AES/mode/padding` transforms) supports _all_ AES key sizes: 128 (16 bytes), 192 (24 bytes), or 256 (32 bytes). Note old versions of Java _from Sun/Oracle_ (before 2017, specifically below 8u151 or 9) had a 'limited' crypto policy which didn't allow AES over 128 bits, unless you installed a separate 'unlimited policy' file, which was supposed to be unavailable to 'bad' countries. That is no longer needed, and never was for OpenJDK. @Majid: there's no such type or syntax in Java

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake on my side. If Java is given an 256 bit key, then it uses AES-256 with it (as long as it is available on the JDK). My code was wrong.